# How to run LASER sentence embeddings on GPU?

Tags: python, facebook, embedding

I have a 11 million sentences corpus that I need to vectorize to do further comparisons. Everything works just fine, with the exception that it is incredibly slow on a CPU (~6 sentences per second).
The call to LASER library is very simple and it doesn't have more parameters to tune-up.

```
from laserembeddings import Laser
laser = Laser()

vector = laser.embed_sentences("this is a test", lang="en")
```

On the [LASER](https://engineering.fb.com/2019/01/22/ai-research/laser-multilingual-sentence-embeddings/) homepage they claim:

> It delivers extremely fast performance, processing up to 2,000
> sentences per second on GPU.

How can I make use of my GPU for this task?

**SOLUTION**:
I installed PyTorch with CUDA support and LASER directly starts using the GPU:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this [library](https://github.com/yannvgn/laserembeddings) I assume? What GPU do you have? Is it `cuda` supported?

From this [source](https://github.com/yannvgn/laserembeddings/blob/ceb3818c998099d315a935210d3962640922fa8b/laserembeddings/embedding.py#L24), it looks like GPU support is enabled by default.

Can you check if `pytorch` can reach your GPU?

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Comment: I'm installing torch with CUDA support enabled as we speak. My GPU is a NVidia RTX 3080 so it should work just fine. The is_available() function was returning False. So I think this is the right direction of things to try, thank you very much.